# Enterprise Library 5, Store Validation Rules in Database

Tags: validation, enterprise-library

is there a way to store validation rules for EL in a database?
Our model allows for dynamic attributes in business classes. Their definition is stored in a table. In that same table I would like to store validation rules for the attributes.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SqlConfigurationSource](http://entlib.codeplex.com/releases/view/56812).